# Using value of complex ng-model in controller from template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have input box inside a loop in HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="line in list.performance_recommendations"> 
       <label>{{line.template.message}} 
                <input class="k-textbox" value="{{line.template.new_value}}" type="number" ng-model="line.template.new_value">
       </label> 
</div>
```

This is sample data:

```
      list.performance_recommendations = [
  {
   id : 121,
   template : {
       message : "Stop",
       new_value : 232,
      }
  },
  {
   id : 122,
   template : {
       message : "Paused",
       new_value : 23232,
      }
  }
 ]
```

How can I use this ng-model inside my angularjs controller?

**$scope.line.template.new_value  is not woking.**

Comment: What do you mean it's "not working"?  What happens when you console.log() it? undefined?

Comment: This is actula error :   TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined

Comment: Then we need the code of the corresponding controller, especially the definition of `list.performance_recommendations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to `line` as it is a local variable, it's not defined on the `$scope`. Try updating your HTML to:

```
<div ng-repeat="line in list.performance_recommendations"> 
       <label>{{line.template.message}} 
                <input class="k-textbox" value="{{line.template.new_value}}" type="number" ng-model="$parent.list.performance_recommendations[$index].template.new_value">
       </label> 
</div>
```

I've created [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cda22a88/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: How will I use this ng-model value in my controller ?

Comment: You bind to the list, not to the `line` variable that is instantiated by `ng-repeat`

Comment: Error is coming in my controller not in rendering HTML page

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want the controller to be 'notified' once the user changes a value in the input box?

Comment: Yeah , You are correct  .... now its working ..Thank you very much . I was stuck with this for long time. :)